# Navigation Back Button Not Showing up in xamarin forms page outside a masterpage after i set NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xamarin-forms-4

I set has  NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True" in xamarin forms but its not showing up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Skit.Views.Profile"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">
```

This is what i have on my profile page, i want it to return to main page after i click back arrow in title bar